# Programming Practice and Principles chapter 6 calculator bugs

Tags: c++, c++11

**I easily found all the compile time errors, but the dang program still won't compile. In fact the only error I ever got was:**

```
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BJST chap 6 calc 2.0\Debug
\BJST chap 6 calc 2.0.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I realize this must mean that the compiler is looking for files that aren't in the right place. Is this an intentional bug/error with Strousstrup's program? Maybe something else wrong with the configuration of my compiler??

The program I as have fixed the compiler bugs is below:

```
//
// This is example code from Chapter 6.7 "Trying the second version" of
// "Software - Principles and Practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

/*
    This file is known as calculator02buggy.cpp

    I have inserted 5 errors that should cause this not to compile
    I have inserted 3 logic errors that should cause the program to give wrong results

    First try to find an remove the bugs without looking in the book.
    If that gets tedious, compare the code to that in the book (or posted source code)

    Happy hunting!

*/

#include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value 
    Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }    
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Token_stream {
public: 
    Token_stream();   // make a Token_stream that reads from cin
    Token get();      // get a Token (get() is defined elsewhere)
    void putback(Token t);    // put a Token back
private:
    bool full;        // is there a Token in the buffer?
    Token buffer;     // here is where we keep a Token put back using putback()
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The constructor just sets full to indicate that the buffer is empty:
Token_stream::Token_stream()
:full(false), buffer(0)    // no Token in buffer
{
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The putback() member function puts its argument back into the Token_stream's buffer:
void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
    if (full) error("putback() into a full buffer");
    buffer = t;       // copy t to buffer
    full = true;      // buffer is now full
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) {       // do we already have a Token ready?
        // remove token from buffer
        full=false;
        return buffer;
    } 

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
    case ';':    // for "print"
    case 'q':    // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': 
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '9':
        {    
            cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
            double val;
            cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
            return Token('8',val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
        }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token_stream ts;        // provides get() and putback() 

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double expression();    // declaration so that primary() can call expression()

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with numbers and parentheses
double primary()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '(':    // handle '(' expression ')'
        {    
            double d = expression();
            t = ts.get();
            if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected");
            return d;
        }
    case '8':            // we use '8' to represent a number
        return t.value;  // return the number's value
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with *, /, and %
double term()
{
    double left = primary();
    Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

    while(true) {
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':
            left *= primary();
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '/':
            {    
                double d = primary();
                if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
                left /= d; 
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            }
        default: 
            ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
            return left;
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// deal with + and -
double expression()
{

    double left = term();      // read and evaluate a Term
    Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token from token stream

    while(true) {    
        switch(t.kind) {
        case '+':
            left += term();    // evaluate Term and add
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '-':
            left -= term();    // evaluate Term and subtract
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        default: 
            ts.putback(t);     // put t back into the token stream
            return left;       // finally: no more + or -: return the answer
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
try
{
    while (cin) {

        double val = 0;

        Token t = ts.get();

        if (t.kind == 'q') break; // 'q' for quit
        if (t.kind == ';')        // ';' for "print now"
            cout << "=" << val << '\n';
        else
            ts.putback(t);
        val = expression();
    }
    keep_window_open();
}
catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n'; 
    keep_window_open();
    return 1;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n"; 
    keep_window_open();
    return 2;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Its not a compilation error. Its a linker error.

Comment: you're most likely building using Visual Studio and selected the wrong project type or so (windows instead of console). Give me some time to find the duplicate questions :]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Opengl program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632340/cannot-run-opengl-program) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983678/error-lnk-1120-and-lnk-2001 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487002/why-wont-this-work-second-function-wont-register

Comment: Read comments under this [quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18500250)

Comment: thank you. I was using MS Visual Stuido C++ 2010, and your clue pointed me in the right direction. I left one of the other boxes checked along with create "empty project". Unchecking the box below"empty project" it fixed the issue.